# display <li> line wise CSS

Tags: css

I have multiple li-a tags with varying size of text inside it. How can I display this line wise. As of now all the li -a  tags are squeezing in one line and I want it in seperate lines. Should be able to handle single line and multiple line of text..

```
<ul>

   <li><a>AAAA </a></li>
   <li><a>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB </a></li>
   <li><a>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</a></li>
   <li><a>DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</a></li>


 </ul>
```

Display should be:

```
AAAA                                                     
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                 
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC                          
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

As of now it is:

```
AAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

**CSS**

```
ul li a{
  line-height: 45px;   
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  margin-left:10px
}
```

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/Bt2hU/

Comment: show us your full code might be some css is missed out

Comment: Your part of code is correct. You are probably including some `CSS` resets to page, or another `CSS` files that set attributes to `UL`.

Comment: @Rakesh Shetty thanks for pointing out the jsfiddle. It does work in there, but I don't see it that way in my webapp.

Comment: @M1K10, yes it does seem am resetting the options by the above code is my custom css and am loading it at the very end. I am using bootstrap, bootstrapValidator and bootstraptheme.js besides this custom one.

Comment: Sorry, my late night silliness. li is working as it should be. I was actually looking at a label that was not inside li and hence the texts coming in one line. But the li's inside it were fine. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score -1):

li is block element it has to work by default. But somewhere you have changed to line that why it didnt work, so reset adding block as given below

Add display:block to li element

```
ul li{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: without display:block working fine with the OP code http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/Bt2hU/

Comment: @RakeshShetty li is block element it has to work by default. But it doesnt work in his existing code, so some where he set inline to li element. Thats why I given code to reset block